# how to combine slick carousel features

Tags: javascript, carousel, slick.js

I am trying to use the slick carousel from this website http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and I am trying to use multiple features. There is some overlapping code that is probably causing problems. Autoplay and fade is not working with the other features. A simple deletion of some of the repetitive code should make this code function.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.carousel').slick({

            /* Multiple */
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3

            /* Variable Width */
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            centerMode: true,
            variableWidth: true

            /* Autoplay */
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,

            /* Fade */
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            fade: true,
            cssEase: 'linear'

        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you calling it 4 times for the same carousel(s)?

Comment: yes and the functions will eventually be combined into 1 function

Comment: But do you have 4 carousels? Or do you have one and you want to call the slick carousel for it 4 times (if that's the case - why?) ?

Comment: i have 1 carousel and I want to call it 1 time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a JS fiddle using your code. The carousel works, but it needs some styling: http://jsfiddle.net/77vsunov/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.carousel').slick({

        /* Multiple */
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,

        /* Variable Width */
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true,

        /* Autoplay */
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,

        /* Fade */
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear'

    });
});
```

I took your code, added the needed commas and it appears to be working properly.